# Images not showing up on a mac

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, file-upload

I have setup up a simple file upload system using laravel.
To store the image, I set up my controller as

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $menu = new Menu;
    $menu->title = $request->get('menuTitle');
    $menu->user_id = Auth::id();


    if($request->hasFile('menuImage')){
        $filenameWithExt = $request->file('menuImage')->getClientOriginalName();
        $fileName = pathinfo($filenameWithExt,PATHINFO_FILENAME); 
        $ext = $request->file('menuImage')->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $fileNameToStore = $fileName.'_'.time().'.'.$ext;
        $path = $request->file('menuImage')->storeAs('public/menu',$fileNameToStore); 
    }
    else{
        $fileNameToStore = 'blank.jpg';
    }
    $menu->image_name = $fileNameToStore;
    $menu->save();
    return redirect(route('menu.create'))->with('success',$menu->title." Added successfully");

}
```

In the view I set it up as

```
<a href="#">
      <img class="img-fluid rounded mb-3 mb-md-0"  src={{asset("/storage/menu/".$menu->image_name)}} alt="">
    </a>
```

In the browser the link is

```
<img class="img-fluid rounded mb-3 mb-md-0" src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/menu/Screenshot_20190517_023111_1558916284.png" alt="">
```

While developing, I was working on ubuntu and everything works fine. However, I transferred my files to my mac and using xampp I was able to get everything working. However the images do not load anymore. I get a 404 error when I check the console. However, the images are able to upload to the right folder.

Comment: can you please check image stored in your storage path?

Answer (score 0):

You should run `php artisan storage:link` so that the `storage/app/public` will be linked to `public/storage` directory and your link will work again